# Why does float('inf') == float('inf') return True, but float('inf') - float('inf') == float('inf') returns False?

Tags: python, infinity

Why does this happen in Python?

- `float('inf') == float('inf')` returns `True`,
- `float('inf') + float('inf') == float('inf')` returns `True`,
- `float('inf') * float('inf') == float('inf')` returns `True`,
- `float('inf') - float('inf') == float('inf')` returns `False`,
- `float('inf') / float('inf') == float('inf')` returns `False`.

My best guess, if I think about limits, is related with the result of this operation:

lim<sub>x→+∞</sub>(f(x) ▢ g(x)) where lim<sub>x→+∞</sub> f(x) = +∞ and lim<sub>x→+∞</sub> g(x) = +∞,  which returns +∞ if ▢ is + or *, but it is not defined (it could return every value) if ▢ is - or /.

I am very puzzled, though.

Comment: Because `float('inf') - float('inf')` is `nan`, not `inf`. Since `nan != inf`, `inf - inf` is not equal to `inf`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Why `float('inf') - float('inf')` is `float('nan)`?

Comment: Because it's indeterminate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infty-infty, known as the Hilbert hotel paradox

Comment: The rules for infinities are not always intuitive, but this is how it is.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you. On a related note, I just found that Python is implemented accordingly with the [IEEE 754-1985 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) which defines the "rules" for infinity.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I edited the question. Now it is readable also with dark theme

Comment: Thanks. I even found a draft online. I extended the answer to mention chapter 7.2 of IEEE754.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why you would expect infinity minus infinity to equal infinity. If you had any expectation about it at all, surely you would expect it to be 0 or undefined?

Comment: @kaya3 I never said that I expect ∞ - ∞ = ∞. I said that I did not know for sure why ∞ - ∞ = NaN (even though I imagined it already), and I have received some very clear explanations about it!
To answer to your question, it seems to me that ∞ - ∞ can "sometimes" be equal to ∞ (e.g. uncountable minus countable sets), but it can also be equal to any other number.

Comment: Your question asks why it returns false; surely you must have some reason for expecting it to return something other than false, or you would not ask the question. And the only thing other than false it can return is true. So if you don't have any reason to suppose that the result should be true, what are you actually asking?

Comment: @kaya3 I am not a computer. My brain does not work in terms of `True` or `False` only. My brain also has `Ignorant`. In this case my answer to `float('inf') - float('inf') == float('inf')` would have been 'Ignorant', or at most `sometimes True, sometimes False`.

Comment: But you are not ignorant of the result - you know that it is false, and you knew that before you posted the question, because you wrote yourself in your own question title that the result is false. So if you don't have a reason to think it should be otherwise, again, what is the actual question? It seems to me nobody could wonder why two things aren't equal if there is no reason that they might be equal.

Comment: @kaya3 my bad most probably. The post could be misleading.
Do not look at the title only. I did not ask why `False` instead of `True`, I asked why a result is returned whatsoever (i.e. what is the theory leading to any of the five results you see).
In fact, I asked why five things happen, and not only why `float('inf') - float('inf') == float('inf')` is `False`. Fortunately, somebody has been very kind and gave an exhaustive explanation already.

And to be entirely honest, my initial concern arose because I expected `float('inf') == float('inf')` to be `False`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242785/discussion-between-pietro-dantuono-and-kaya3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before the comparison of

```
float('inf') - float('inf') == float('inf')
```

can be made, the result of

```
float('inf') - float('inf')
```

will be calculated. That [result is `NaN`](https://onlinegdb.com/vhgJUFGfR).

It is NaN because the amounts of infinity may differ. It's explained on the Stack Overflow sister site [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infty-infty), known as the Hilbert hotel paradox:

> From a layman's perspective, imagine that I have an infinite number of hotel rooms, each numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
>
> Then I give you all of them. I would have none left, so ∞−∞=0
>
> On the other hand, if I give you all of the odd-numbered ones, then I still have an infinite number left. So ∞−∞=∞.
>
> Now suppose that I give you all of them except for the first seven. Then ∞−∞=7.
> While this doesn't explain why this is indeterminate, hopefully you can agree that it is indeterminate!

The best number to represent *indeterminate* is NaN. Comparing NaN to anything is always `False`, even [comparing NaN against itself](https://onlinegdb.com/gXMIVc-5P).

Besides that quite "logical" explanation, we find that [Python uses IEEE754](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) representation for floating point calculation.

You'd typically need to [buy the IEEE754 specification](https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/754/6210/), but luckily we see [some draft version online](https://irem.univ-reunion.fr/IMG/pdf/ieee-754-2008.pdf). The relevant chapter IMHO is 7.2:

> For operations producing results in floating-point format, the default result of an operation that signals the
> invalid operation exception shall be a quiet NaN [...]
>
> [...]
>
> d) addition or subtraction or fusedMultiplyAdd: magnitude subtraction of infinities, such as:
> addition(+∞, −∞)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's a problem with python.

`infinity - infinity` is undefined (mathematically), therefore it is not be equal to infinity.

---

```py
>>> np.inf - np.inf
nan
```

```py
>>> np.inf == np.inf
True
```

makes sense, we're comparing objects that are equal.

```py
>>> (np.inf - np.inf) == np.inf
False
```

Also makes sense, we're comparing different objects.

All the answers python gave you, on the examples you posted, are right.

Answer (score 1):

See answer by @thomas-weller but additionally, the issue boils down to this. Because there are multiple sizes of infinite we run into a problem when subtracting and dividing them.

Setting aside recent proof that some infinite sets thought to be of different size are in fact the the same size ([Mathematicians Measure Infinities and Find They’re Equal](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-measure-infinities-find-theyre-equal-20170912/)).

The list of whole numbers is infinite and the list of real numbers is also infinite. However, the list of real numbers between any two adjacent whole numbers is also infinite.

`float("inf")` does not give a chance to say "this is infinite" vs "this is infinitely infinite" so we don't know which it is. Note I'm going to use two references from here on:

- INF === infinite
- INFINF === infinitely infinite

Now then where does that leave us:

`float('inf') == float('inf') ==> True`

It seems reasonable that: `(INF or INFINF) is equal to (INF or INFINF)`

`float('inf') + float('inf') == float('inf')`

It seems reasonable that: `(INF or INFINF) + (INF or INFINF) is equal to (INF or INFINF)`

`float('inf') * float('inf') == float('inf')`

It seems reasonable that: `(INF or INFINF) * (INF or INFINF) is equal to (INF or INFINF)`

`float('inf') - float('inf') == float('inf')`

Now we have a bit of a stickler. We conceptually have lots of potential answers. Given `float('inf') - float('inf')` then `0` is plausible as is `-INFINF` and `INFINF`. This result is undefined and as such `nan`. In fact, as @thomas-weller points out almost any answer might be plausible.

`float('inf') / float('inf') == float('inf')`

Same issue as above. This result is undefined given that we don't know how "big" any of the `float("inf")` are.

Comment: Awesome article, very surprising. Didn't know that. [Original paper here](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2016-29-01/S0894-0347-2015-00830-X/S0894-0347-2015-00830-X.pdf)

Comment: *"recent proofs that all infinities might be the same size"* - that is not at all true, nor is it what the linked article says. Also the fact that there are different infinite cardinalities is kind of irrelevant to this question, because floating-point numbers are not specifically meant to represent cardinalities, there are other notions of infinity besides cardinals; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: True enough. Their proof states that two infinites sets thought to be different size are the same size. I'll update my over simplification.

Comment: *"However, the list of real numbers between any two adjacent whole numbers is also infinite."* - The same is true for *rational* numbers, but the "size" of the set of rational numbers is the same as of the whole numbers. So I don't see your point, and your whole "infinitely infinite" breaks down.